# Should I use multi column or multi table?

Tags: mysql

I have a table currently having 13 columns:

```
    name, gender, age, color, country, a_qps, a_throughput, b_qps, b_throughput, c_qps, c_throughput, d_qps, d_throughput
```

(name, gender, age, color, country) is used as a key for query. a, b, c, d are the mode. The data types of x_qps are the same and the types of x_throughput are the same.

Should I keep them in this table as the types of modes increase? For example, if another new mode e comes, should I add e_qps, e_throughput to the same table?
Or should I do a vertical split of the table and turn this into 4 tables as

```
    name, gender, age, color, country, a_qps, a_throughput
    name, gender, age, color, country, b_qps, b_throughput
    name, gender, age, color, country, c_qps, c_throughput
    name, gender, age, color, country, d_qps, d_throughput
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, you should avoid having dynamic columns or tables, dynamic information should be in cell data. So I would go with a third option, a single table with the mode as a value:

```
name, gender, age, color, country, mode, qps, throughput
```

`mode` would be `a`, `b`, `c`, etc.

You should also add an auto-increment primary key to the main table, so you don't have to repeat all 5 key columns in every other table. That primary key can be used as the foreign key in other tables.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on the data design. If all the data in columns like 
`b_qps, b_throughput, c_qps, c_throughput, d_qps, d_throughput` are strictly bound to the `name, gender, age, color, country, a_qps, a_throughput` and there is unique 1-1 relation between them, keep it in single table. If there will be scenarios that some different relations (1-N) may occure, split into 2 or more tables.

In general, there is nothing wrong in having many columns in single table as long as they are  normalized - no data duplications.

Comment: Thanks @Antoniossss. I think we may keep it untacked.